# one row is missing while splitting the data into train and test using train_test_split in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a dataframe with 175270 rows and 164 columns. When I performed train_test_split one row is missing. I am not able to understand why this strange behaviour with train_test_split.

I never came across this type of behaviour with train_test_split. Please,help me to understand where am gone wrong.

```py
# train_test_split code:
train1, test1 = train_test_split(df, train_size = 0.7, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)
```

I am using above line of code to split the data. But it is missing one row while splitting the data. train1 rows are 122688. test1 rows are 52581. total I have to get 175270 but I am getting 175269.

Comment: This could be because indices are zero-based in Python. Could you check the output of `len(df) == len(train1) + len(test1)` please? Did it return `False`?

Comment: It is giving False

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. This is happening because of a rounding error that gets propagated through the internals of the train_test_split function.

in sklearn.model_selection._split.py

```
    if test_size_type == 'f':
    n_test = ceil(test_size * n_samples)
elif test_size_type == 'i':
    n_test = float(test_size)

if train_size_type == 'f':
    n_train = floor(train_size * n_samples)
elif train_size_type == 'i':
    n_train = float(train_size)
```

both test_size_type and train_size_type will be 'f' when you give the function a decimal point representation for the train/test parameters.

you'll notice:

ceil(0.3 * 175270) = ceil(52581.0) = 52581.0

floor(0.7 * 175270) = floor(122688.99999999999) = 122688

hence you lose a row.

To fix this just use the integer representation

> test_size float or int, default=None
>
> > If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the proportion of the dataset to include in the test split. **If int, represents the absolute number of test samples.** If None, the value is set to the complement of the train size. If train_size is also None, it will be set to 0.25.